# Polymer production app with angular full stack framework-generated by yeoman

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, polymer, yeoman

I am using angular full stack generator by yeoman with polymer as manually injected. I am not using polymer generator and not to sure how to use vulcanise task to include polymer element in production version of the app.

This is how I included polymer in my index.html

```
<!-- 1. Load platform support before any code that touches the DOM. -->
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Load the component using an HTML Import, in this case element list is imported which consists of all required elementLis -->
<link rel="import" href="elements/elementList.html">
```

It works perfectly from local host, but when I run grunt serve: dist 
no polymer element displays on the page, and error logs

angular is trying to load too many times.

I have found some answers from stack overflow that I might have to include vulcanise task in grunt to be able to include polymer html.

I want to be able to include any polymer element and relevant css files from a certain directory for the dist version of the application.

I am new to polymer and still learning grunt.. Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is my polymer element directory..

https://github.com/knofler/angular-fullstack-base/tree/master/client/elements

Comment: do you use bower to install this library?

Comment: Yes I did, but from grunt I put polymer.html and webcomponent.js on exclude list to prevent auto injection to index.html as this causes polymer.html loading multiple times and causes browser to crash ..